# Apache RewriteRule with cookie

Tags: apache, drupal-7

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} DRUPAL_UID  [OR]
 RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
 RewriteRule .* - [S=3]
```

As i know from above code, if:

https request, cookie DRUPAL_UID exists, status 200

it will skip 3 RewriteRule.

Is is correct?

And how to change the cookie condition to DRUPAL_UID  > 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is correct, as long as your rules are correct the `OR` condition should satisfy that.

To satisfy cookie ID > 0:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} DRUPAL_UID=[1-9].* [NC]`

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} DRUPAL_UID=[1-9].* [NC]  [OR]
 RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
 RewriteRule .* - [S=3]            It's not working. Cookie>0 doesn't skip the rule afterthat.